# Accessing resources defined in Controls Library

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

So I have got a few `DataTemplate`s in a User Control Library. These `DataTemplate`s reside in `themes\generic.xaml` resource dictionary and can be consumed in the library project without problem.

This library project is used by the main desktop application project, but at runtime `Application.Current.FindResource()` cannot locate any of the resources defined in the library. (I thought it would!)

So I went ahead and merged that resource dictionary into Application resource dictionary:

```
<Application x:Class="Application">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ControlsLibraryProj;component/themes/generic.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and voila! it can now access those `DataTemplate`s. My question is, did I do it correctly? Do I need to merge a dictionary defined in a referenced project? Somehow I have the impression that `Application.Current.FindResource()` would have access to all the resources defined in all loaded modules (exe and dll). Is that correct and have I unnecessarily loaded them twice by merging?

Comment: Is the User Control Library a third part assembly or your own assmbly?

Comment: @IlVic: It's my own library and available as a project in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, did I do it correctly?

Yes.

> Do I need to merge a dictionary defined in a referenced project?

Yes, if you intend to actually use the styles defined in the referenced Project in your app project.

The only exception is the default control styles, i.e. the default styles for any controls that are defined in the referenced project. These are the ones that you typically define in `themes/generic.xaml` and these will be applied to any instances of the corresponding Controls that you create in your application without you having to merge `themes/generic.xaml`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote the user control library by your own, I would rather suggest you using `generic.xaml` for declaring resources just for your custom controls. If you do not want to or you cannot do it, IMHO you should use [ComponentResourceKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.componentresourcekey(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can find a sample [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2007/06/08/defining-and-using-shared-resources-in-a-custom-control-library/) (take a look to the "Defining resources at the theme level" section).

So your resource will be declared as:

```
<LinearGradientBrush
        x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:Painter}, ResourceId=ButtonBrush}" 
        StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset=".8" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

And you can retrieve it

```
ComponentResourceKey brushKey = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(Painter), "MyEllipseBrush");
ellipseBrush = (Brush)Application.Current.TryFindResource(brushKey);
```

Please pay attention because:

> Implicit style application does not occur on the theme level.  Suppose
>   you want all the labels on your controls to have a certain style.  If
>   you define the style in at the element level, you do not have to give
>   the style an explicit key, the labels will use the style
>   automatically.  This is not the case for resources at the theme level.
>   You must define a key and reference the style every place you want to
>   use it.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That is certainly an interesting way of doing it.